# SQl Add values in columns wihout loss in precision

Tags: sql, precision, addition

I have a table with 5 columns, 4 of which are decimal data type (18, 2). I want to add the values of these four without loss of precision.
If I do `Select column1, column2+column3+column4+column5` I get a total that is some decimals higher than the actual total. However, if I just do a select on all the columns and export the result to excel, the sum of these four columns in excel is accurate. How can I achieve high accuracy in excel column value addition?

Comment: Cast one of the columns to decimal(20,2) when adding.

Comment: tried that but did not work

Comment: Can you post some sample data along with the correspong schema and the query you have tried? Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: actually @jarlh suggestion worked. I had to do this on some specific columns

Comment: I would suggest then posting the solution as an answer, so that other readers may benefit from this in the futute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast at least one of the columns to decimal(20,2) when adding, something like

```
select cast(column1 as decimal(20,2)) + column2 + column3 + column4 + column5
```